# Selling Digital Goods using the REST API

Tags: api, rest, paypal

I'm trying to use the Express Checkout REST API to sell digital goods on my website.

The main problem I'm facing is that PayPal is showing the "Ship To" in the order review.

Is it possible to disable, or remove shipping when creating a payment using the REST API?

I saw a related question here: [Selling Digital goods via REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495839/selling-digital-goods-via-rest-api) - however it's old and there hasn't been any update for a while. Basically it says the REST API doesn't support selling digital goods.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to disable shipping by creating an Experience Profile, 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/

I used an application called Postman to send a POST request to PayPal on https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles

With this JSON data:

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "presentation": {
    "brand_name": "AppName Paypal",
    "locale_code": "US"
  },
  "input_fields": {
    "no_shipping": 1,
    "address_override": 1
  },
  "flow_config": {
    "landing_page_type": "login"
  }
}
```

Please note that I used no_shipping 1, which disables shipping. I also sent the Authorization Bearer token with this POST request.

If the request is successful, then you'll get the id of the newly created experience profile.
The id is used when creating an express checkout payment.

```
"experience_profile_id":"experience_profile_id",
```